# PDF stored in database not displaying in the views in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that can upload images and display them on the view; it can also upload PDFs, but does not display the PDF on the view. I would like to know how to display a PDF in the views.

#### Here is my code:

My Model:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    
    namespace TembisaAFM.Models
    {
    
       
            public class Person
            {
                public int ID { get; set; }
    
                [Required]
                [StringLength(50)]
                [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                [Required]
                [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
                [Column("FirstName")]
                [Display(Name = "First Name")]
                public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    
                [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
                public string FullName
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
                    }
                }
                public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class File
            {
                public int FileId { get; set; }
                [StringLength(255)]
                public string FileName { get; set; }
                [StringLength(100)]
                public string ContentType { get; set; }
                public byte[] Content { get; set; }
                public FileType FileType { get; set; }
                public int PersonId { get; set; }
                public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class FilePath
            {
                public int FilePathId { get; set; }
                [StringLength(255)]
                public string FileName { get; set; }
                public FileType FileType { get; set; }
                public int PersonID { get; set; }
                public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
            }
    
            public enum FileType
            {
                 Avatar = 1, Photo
            }
    
    
            public class PersonDBContext : DbContext
            {
                public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
                public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
                public DbSet<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
    
            }
    
        }
```

My Controllers:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using TembisaAFM.Models;
    
    namespace TembisaAFM.Controllers
    {
        public class PeopleController : Controller
        {
            private PersonDBContext db = new PersonDBContext();
    
            // GET: People
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(db.People.ToList());
            }
    
    
            // GET: People/Details/5
            public ActionResult Details(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
    
                Person person = db.People.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
                if (person == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
           
                return View(person);
            }
    
    
            public ActionResult GeneratePDF(int? id)
    
    
            {
    
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
    
                Person person = db.People.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
                if (person == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Details", person) { FileName = "Details.pdf" };
              
            } 
    
            // GET: People/Create
            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
            // POST: People/Create
            // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
            // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,LastName,FirstMidName")] Person person, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
    
    
                    if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var avatar = new File
                        {
                            FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                            FileType = FileType.Avatar,
                            ContentType = upload.ContentType
                        };
                        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                        {
                            avatar.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                        }
                        person.Files = new List<File> { avatar };
                    }
                    db.People.Add(person);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
    
                return View(person);
            }
    
            // GET: People/Edit/5
            public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
    
    
                Person person = db.People.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.ID == id);
                if (person == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(person);
            }
    
    
    
    
            // POST: Student/Edit/5
            // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
            // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
            [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult EditPost(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                var studentToUpdate = db.People.Find(id);
                if (TryUpdateModel(studentToUpdate, "",
                   new string[] { "LastName", "FirstMidName" }))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (studentToUpdate.Files.Any(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar))
                            {
                                db.Files.Remove(studentToUpdate.Files.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar));
                            }
                            var avatar = new File
                            {
                                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName),
                                FileType = FileType.Avatar,
                                ContentType = upload.ContentType
                            };
                            using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                            {
                                avatar.Content = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                            }
                            studentToUpdate.Files = new List<File> { avatar };
                        }
                        db.Entry(studentToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
    
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
                    {
                        //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                    }
                }
                return View(studentToUpdate);
            }
    
            // GET: People/Delete/5
            public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                Person person = db.People.Find(id);
                if (person == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(person);
            }
    
            // POST: People/Delete/5
            [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
            {
                Person person = db.People.Find(id);
                db.People.Remove(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
    
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
    }
```

My Details View:

```
    @model TembisaAFM.Models.Person
    
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
        Layout = null;
    
    }
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
    
                <h3>Details</h3>
    
            </div>
    
                <hr />
    
    
    
    
    
                <table class="table table-striped">
    
    
                    <tr>
    
                        <td> Avatar</td>
                      @var getData = ViewData["PDF"];
                        <td><img src="~/File?id=@Model.Files.First(f => f.FileType == FileType.Avatar).FileId" alt="avatar" /></td>
    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
    
                        <td>Last Name</td>
    
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
    
    
                    </tr>
    
    
                    <tr>
    
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName)</td>
    
                    </tr>
    
    
                    <tr>
    
                        <td>Last Name</td>
    
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
    
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstMidName)</td>
    
                    </tr>
    
    
    
                    <tr>
    
                        
                        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.ID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") |
                        @Html.ActionLink("PDF", "GeneratePDF", new { id = Model.ID }) |</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Print" onclick="window.print()">
    
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    
                </table>
            
    
                </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    </div>
```

My Create View:

```
    @model TembisaAFM.Models.Person
    
    
    
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }
    
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "People", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Person</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstMidName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstMidName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstMidName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Avatar", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" id="Avatar" name="upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Comment: Is Rotativa.ActionAsPdf method returning FileResult, or just relative path string? PDF files require `<object>` or `<embed>` tag with `src` attribute assigned to relative path on rendering inside view.

Comment: public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
{   byte[] byteArray = GetPdfFromDB();
    MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfStream.Write(byteArray , 0,byteArray .Length);
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=form.pdf");

    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");

Answer (score 0):

you can test the PDF generation by using following code.

```
public ActionResult DisplayPDF()
 {   
  byte[] byteArray = File.Content;[Put your content property of File class]
  MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
  pdfStream.Write(byteArray , 0,byteArray .Length);
  pdfStream.Position = 0;
  HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
  "attachment; filename=form.pdf");

  return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: I am getting error for GetPdfFromDB() and filestream like,
The name 'GetPdfFromDB' does not exist in the current context and also
name 'fileStream' does not exist in the current context.I added System.IO;
,System.IO.Stream; and System.IO.FileStream; namaspaces.

Comment: Hi, that was just example function, Just put your File class content data there.